# Left Alt+tab and Left Ctrl+Left Shift+tab is not working on my external keyboard

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout, alt-tab

I have been using the **EXTERNAL keyboard** for the Linux Mint desktop. 
Recently **Left Alt+tab** ( to switch between the currently opened windows ) and **LeftCtrl+LeftShift + tab** ( to go to the previous tab in chrome )  stopped working.

**Note:** If I use the Right ( Cntrl, Shift, alt ) keys for the above combination it works fine. And Left ( Cntrl, Shift, alt ) are working (not for the above combinations )

If there is a way to fix it, let me know.
Thanks in advance :D

**Edit:**
Output for following Commands

**xev**

```
KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1530392, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1532104, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1532824, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1534480, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1539400, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1539496, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1539520, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1539576, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x11, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x6a7, subw 0x0, time 1542144, (157,-10), root:(742,289),
    state 0x15, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

**setxkbmap -print**

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Comment: `stopped working` ... did you make any software changes that caused the left side buttons to stop working?

Comment: @jsotola no i didnt make any changes

Comment: all of this information belongs in the question above, not in comments ... please use the edit button to update the post, then delete the comments

Comment: Have you tried using this keyboard with another computer to be sure it isn't a keyboard issue ?  In general please tell us all of the things you have tried.

Comment: @PatrickTaylor yeah the problem is with the keyboard only. I have tried the same keyboard with another laptop and the **problem exists**

Comment: Since it started happening it sounds like it might be worn out.  It might be worth checking if it's configurable somehow and you accidentally hit the magic combination.

Comment: @PatrickTaylor is there any way to resolve this. since I don't know many things about configuration and all.

Comment: This is something you have to check with the keyboard manufacturer.  I do know that the keyboard I use (logi MX keys) can be configured to do different things but it is manufacturer and model dependent.

Comment: @PatrickTaylor oh okay!!.. Thanks for your time  :D